# Play swf game using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, flash, cocos2d-x

Is there a way to run an swf file (without using a browser) using C++?
I need to launch an swf game and pass some parameters for it to load properly. I have a win32 application. Using a button in my app, I need to start up the game. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

By the way, I'm using cocos2dx for my UI. (maybe this information can help)

Comment: Run it in any browser-like component? Like QWebView in QT. If it's windows - probably you can use IWebBrowser2

Comment: will IWebBrowser launch a new window? is it a popup? Sorry, I haven't used IWebBrowser2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to launch the swf game, with the correct parameters, then the most cross platform way would be to use `exec` probably, and run the [Flash Standalone Player](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html). This will play the flash movie in its own window.

Otherwise, loading the [NPAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Guide) version of the Flash Browser plugin is not too difficult, and will allow you to embed the flash game within your Cocos2d-x application, assuming your are happy hacking the Cocos2d-x code enough to get your windows' OS window handle.

A third way would be to load the ActiveX version of the control, but thats just a horrid technology to work with and requires your app to have administrative privileges to install the control if it was not already installed.

The Standalone and NPAPI players can be bundled and used from your app directly.

---

Edit: For some reason I thought `exec` was a standard C function but it seems to not actually be so. So, launching the flash standalone player with a command line using `CreateProcess` would look like this:

```
LPCTSTR pathToFlashPlayer = TEXT(".\\bin\\flashplayer18_sa_win_32.exe");
LPCTSTR pathToSwf = TEXT(".\\res\\content.swf");

STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si), 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
auto success = CreateProcess(
  pathToFlashPlayer,
  pathToSwf,
  NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL,
  &si, &pi);
if(success){
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Comment: hi Chris. Thanks for your answer.
if i want to use the first option, do you have a tutorial i can follow/read so I can get a head start? I'm new to all of these and I would appreciate all the help I could get. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have added a sample for using CreateProcess. 'exec' is not quite the standard way for launching processes that I thought.

Comment: Launching the Flash player is going to be really troublesome - unless you're targeting only your machine. Most users won't have the standalone Flash player installed and the executable name might not be the one that this answer gives - it changes per version - eg. mine is flashplayer_17_sa_debug.exe). You also don't have rights to distribute it online.

Comment: NPAPI has also been either phased out, or is being phased out by pretty much everybody (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#Browser_support). So, if your end users has only IE installed (for example), then they won't have the Flash plugin either... so, also not a great options for compatibility.

Comment: thank you. i will try this out. one question though, what if i want to pass a parameters to swf when launching, how should i do it?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito so what do you suggest is the good thing to do?

Comment: @cessmestreet see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed a playing SWF into your application, without using a browser of any sort, you'll need to embed a Flash runtime into your application. [Scaleform](http://www.autodesk.com/products/scaleform/overview) is probably the best known 3rd party Flash runtime, and has a C++ interface.

Comment: thank you for this but this will require me to use another studio, right? I was hoping to find like a library i could use or a command or something similar. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: It is only the runtime - you need to create your assets in some way - generally though Flash Studio, although you could use Flash Develop, among other tools. But, from your question, it sounds like you already have a .swf file you'd like to play - in that case, you just need to integrate the Scaleform library (or other Flash runtime), and play it your assets.

Comment: HI @muertoexcobito thank you for your quick reply. i'm not familiar with scaleform library, can you point me to a good tutorial or guide? i would love to take a look at it and try it out. thank you so much :)

Comment: The link in my answer goes to their website.